# How do I let the OneDrive app automatically list libraries you are assigned to?

Tags: central-administration, document-management

So, I'm setting up Sharepoint to create a cloud file server and I'm having trouble automating library syncing with local OneDrive applications. For example, I created a few libraries (i.e. Financials, reports, Office Dakota, etc.) and assigned them to myself and a few other employees. Now, when I sign in to OneDrive on my Mac or my iPhone (The app, not the web version), only my personal folders inside OneDrive are shown. I, sadly, have to add those libraries manually.

This would be a huge job doing this for each new member for each folder seperately. Isn't there a way to have all libraries been added to your 'personal OneDrive' by default, without any action by the employee him-/herself?